# Node cannot be found in the current page using React-Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am trying to use react-select to create a custom drop down component in a React-TS app. The component builds fine but I can't fire the onChange() handler when I click on a drop down. When I try and inspect the drop down elements the dev tools outputs `Node cannot be found in the current page.`

I don't know how to debug this... any advice would be appreciated!

```
const options: OptionType[] = [
  {
    value: "Morphology",
    label: "Morphemes",
    subtitle:
      "Morphological awareness improves reading comprehension and vocabulary.",
  },
  {
    value: "Phonics",
    label: "Phonemes",
    subtitle:
      "Phonemic awareness helps learners recognize individual phonemes (sound units) in spoken words.",
  },
  {
    value: "Spellings",
    label: "Spellings",
    subtitle:
      "Graphemic awareness helps learners understand how letters (graphemes) are used to represent phonemes",
  },
];
export default function ActivitySelector({
  selected,
  handleSelected,
}: ActivitySelectorProps) {
  const CustomOption: React.FC<OptionProps<OptionType, false>> = ({ data }) => (
    <DropDownContainer>
      <DropdownOption>
        <span>{data.label}</span>
      </DropdownOption>
      <Subtitle>{data.subtitle}</Subtitle>
    </DropDownContainer>
  );

  return (
    <Select
      onChange={(selectedOption) => console.log(selectedOption?.value)}
      defaultValue={options[2]}
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={({ label }) => label}
      getOptionValue={({ value }) => value}
      components={{
        Option: CustomOption,
      }}
      styles={{
        control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
          ...baseStyles,
          width: "20rem",
          marginLeft: "1rem",
          marginTop: "1rem",
        }),
      }}
    />
  );
}
```